# Selecting specific contenteditable divs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

Given the following html for a type of blog post editor:

```
<div class="entry">  
  <div class="title" contenteditable="true">
    <h2>Title goes here</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use jquery to select the .title and .content divs to attach unique event handlers to each.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on(...);
```

works for both but

```
$('[contenteditable] .title').on(...);
```

or

```
$('.title').attr('contenteditable', 'true').on(...);
```

both don't work to select the specific contenteditable block.

Comment: The `contenteditable` attribute isn't a Boolean attribute so in theory you should to select a specific attribute value: `$('[contenteditable="true"]')`. I imagine your version probably works though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the attribute selector in CSS `.title[contenteditable="true"]`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tqjU/)

```
.title[contenteditable="true"] {
    background: red;
}
```

In jQuery: `$('.title[contenteditable]').css("background","red")`

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sUDth/)

Comment: I was good with either class or element. To me css class = bonus points :)

Answer (score 3):

For the first example you have to remove the space between the attribute selector and the class selector, as a space implies descendance.

```
$('[contenteditable].title').on("click", function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'orange'); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Bsk4/